# How to update badge count from all view controllers?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I've bunch of badges displaying in tab bar. In my app the badge counts can change anytime as it's a realtime chat app and users can chat from Android, web and iOS app.

Right now I'm fetching badge counts in each and every view controller in my app in `viewWillAppear`. It works but I'm not sure if it's the best way to do it?

Is there any better way to handle this? Any pointer will be appreciated. Tx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create subclass of `UITabBarController` (then you have to set class of your TabBarController to this subclass). Now inside create method and inside this method declare what should happen when current `selectedItem` is *this* or *this* `UITabBarItem` from `tabBar`'s `items` array

```
func changeBadge() {
    guard let item = tabBar.selectedItem else { return }
    guard let items = tabBar.items else { return }
    switch item {
    case items[0]:
        ... // get value
        item.badgeValue = "\(value)"
    case items[1]
        ... // get value
        item.badgeValue = "\(value)"
    ...
    default:
    }
}
```

Now just call this method when `TabBarController` did load and when user select new `UITabBarItem`

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    changeBadge()
}

override func tabBar(_ tabBar: UITabBar, didSelect item: UITabBarItem) {
    changeBadge()
}
```

---

```
class TabBarController: UITabBarController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        changeBadge()
    }

    override func tabBar(_ tabBar: UITabBar, didSelect item: UITabBarItem) {
        changeBadge()
    }

    func changeBadge() {
        guard let item = tabBar.selectedItem else { return }
        guard let items = tabBar.items else { return }
        switch item {
        case items[0]:
            ... // get value
            item.badgeValue = "\(value)"
        case items[1]
            ... // get value
            item.badgeValue = "\(value)"
        ...
        default:
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Good suggestion. I'm working on it. I've one question. How do I trigger didSelect for the Home tab which is displayed by default when app is launched?

Comment: @Dan this method is called automatically when user select certain `UITabBarItem` (means user taps to TabBarItem in TabBar)

Comment: Yes I'm aware of that. I'm asking for the Tab which is shown when app is launched. User doesn't tap on this but this tab is the default first tab which is shown to user when app is launched. I want to show badges when app is launched too. How to do that? In viewWillAppear ?

Comment: You are genius, tx.

Comment: @Dan I'm not genius, I'm just man who is currently in love with Swift and I'm trying to improve my programming "skills" by helping other people. ;)

Comment: @Dan btw, let me know, if it helped.

Comment: I'm trying to make it work. I've got some complexity. I need to update badges in a view controller as well when user takes some action. I can't figure out how can I make above function to be available to both Tab Bar and View Controllers.

Comment: @Dan  Inside your ViewController you can somehow downcast current tab bar controller as your subclass `guard let tab = tabBarController? as? TabBarController else {return}` and then you can call method on this reference `tab.itsMethod()`

Comment: Tx guys, I've managed to make it work. Tx all for help. You guys have been great in helping others.

Answer (score 0):

As you have access of shared instance of **tabBarController**, you can easily increase badge value of its tabBar item in any **UIViewController**. You can do this by following:

```
if let tabBarItems = tabBarController?.tabBar.items {
     let tabItem = tabBarItems[0]
     tabItem.badgeValue = "1"
}
```

Comment: It's again adding this code in each and every view controller which I want to avoid.